# Programs that help you export multi-language videos?

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, editing, adobe, davinci-resolve

I'm looking for a program that can do multi-language export of video.

Let me give an example: I create video with text and I would like to easily add 4 different languages inside each text. The program would export video with that language.

Let's say :

- Importing text in four different languages (for example the program is connected to an Excel file or whatever)
- Exporting four videos with that translated text.

Right now I have major problems because I need to save, then edit the whole video text for each different language, and then export.

Answer (score 0):

[Templater Rig](https://aescripts.com/templater/) can help with this. It's a plugin that connects the text in your After Effects project to a Google Sheet or other spreadsheet. Bear in mind that each language will have different read rates and sentence lengths for the same meaning on-screen, so swapping the translations is only the first step to making the videos look ok.

Comment: Thank you this looks something that i'm looking for. Thank you Tomh

Comment: I spent a lot of time doing this at the bbc a few years back- shared google sheets and templater saved a lot of time, but layout still needed manual intervention https://vimeo.com/42692053

Answer (score 0):

Resolve and Premiere both support .srt files for subtitles, which is what you want instead of "Excel files or whatever."  There are many online services that will generate .srt files from spoken audio, and timestamp them appropriately so that they sync with your video.

Comment: Jason thank you, i didn't understand you right. I don't want from "spoken audio" translation. I will have translated text only.  Let's say Hello and what i want that it will translate and put in video where i placed for first video Hello also 4 other languages and it would export me 4x videos.

Comment: Like the other guy says, each language will have different read rates, which is why you’d use time stamped audio of natural language speakers rather than trying to auto translate. Even if you don’t have separate voiceovers to go with the text, .srt lets you control the read rate of the various languages. Plus, it’s built into each NLE, doesn’t require a third party add on, and on the adobe side, doesn’t require the extra primary package (AE).